# Remove groups based on multiple conditions in dplyr R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidy

I have a data that looks like this

```
gene=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B")
frequency=c(1,1,0.8,0.6,0.3,0.2,1,1)
time=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
df <- data.frame(gene,frequency,time)

  gene frequency time
1    A       1.0    1
2    A       1.0    2
3    A       0.8    3
4    A       0.6    4
5    B       0.3    1
6    B       0.2    2
7    B       1.0    3
8    B       1.0    4
```

I want to  remove each a gene group, in this case A or B when they have
`frequency > 0.9` at `time==1`
In this case I want to remove A  and my data to look like this

```
  gene frequency time
1    B       0.3    1
2    B       0.2    2
3    B       1.0    3
4    B       1.0    4
```

Any hint or help are appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `subset` from `base R` i.e. create a logical vector with multiple expressions extract the 'gene' correspond to that, use `%in%` to create a logical vector, negate (`!`) to return the genes that are not.  Or may also change the `>` to `<=` and remove the `!`

```
subset(df, !gene %in% gene[frequency > 0.9 & time == 1])
```

-ouptut

```
   gene frequency time
5    B       0.3    1
6    B       0.2    2
7    B       1.0    3
8    B       1.0    4
```